# Cant seem to figure out how to call already defined function inside conditional statement

Tags: python

Code below shows my function with a conditional statement in it.
Per option (total of 3) i have a lot of code that i want to write there, but i dont want my conditional statement to become a mess. I was thinking of making a function for each option so that i only have to call that specific function each time. Problem: I cant figure out how to call this function inside the function shown below. Help would be appreciated.

```
def validate_menu():
  option_1 = ['IP cam', 'ip cam', 'ip', '1', 'one']
  option_2 = ['ssh', 'SSH', '2', 'two']
  option_3 = ['ftp', 'FTP', '3', 'three']
  return option_1, option_2, option_3 
#Return to be used in choice_validation function


def choice_validation():
    choice = raw_input('I choose: ')
    option_1, option_2, option_3 = validate_menu()
    if choice in option_1:
       print('Code 1')
    elif choice in option_2:
       print('Code 2')
    elif choice in option_3:
       print('Code 3')
    else:
       print('none')
```

Comment: What's in `validate_menu()`? and can we pack the `Code 1` `Code 2` to different methods? perhaps it would be easier.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what the problem is. You don't know how to *call a function*?

Comment: @user5173426 I edited this post so it has the validate_menu() function. And what do you mean by different methods?

Comment: @Tim0thy Posted an answer below.

Comment: @Aran-Fey i don't know how to call a function that gets defined after the conditional statement.

Comment: @Tim0thy  you define a function outside the conditional statments, perhaps even outside your `choice_validation()` just like you did with `validate_menu()` and then just call if inside like I did in the answer below

Comment: Uh, you can't. You can't call a function that doesn't exist yet. You have to define the function *before* you call it.

Comment: @Tim0thy, has the answer posted below helped? If it did you may accept it by clicking on the tick sign beside it. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Just call it inside the option.
For example:

```
def function(param1, param2):
    #do something

def choice_validation():
    choice = raw_input('I choose: ')
    option_1, option_2, option_3 = validate_menu()
    if choice in option_1:
       function(param1, param2)
    elif choice in option_2:
       function1(param1, param2)
    elif choice in option_3:
       function2(param1, param2)
    else:
       print('none')
```

Answer (score 1):

What I meant:

```
def choice_validation():
    choice = input('I choose: ')
    option_1, option_2, option_3 = validate_menu()
    if choice in option_1:
       code_1_func_()
    elif choice in option_2:
       code_2_func()
    elif choice in option_3:
       code_3_func()
    else:
       print('none')
```